# Why is my for loop telling me Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression"?

Tags: java, for-loop, assignment-operator

I have some code, like so:

```
int batchPosition = new Integer(batchBegin);

for (batchPosition;batchPosition<=batchEnd;batchPosition++)
```

But I get this error in eclipse:

```
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete ForInit.
```

I've looked at various posts on SO about this error, and googled it but I can't figure out why this isn't allowed.

Comment: This may also be because you misspelled 'batchPostion'

Comment: @Kiyura excuse my dyslexia, I couldn't copy from my file so I had to re-write it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`batchPosition` on it's own is not a valid initialisation statement - you can simply skip it:

```
int batchPosition = new Integer(batchBegin);

for (; batchPosition <= batchEnd; batchPosition++)
```

But if you don't need to access `batchPosition` after your loop, it is good practice to reduce variables scopes as much as possible:

```
for (int batchPosition = new Integer(batchBegin); batchPosition <= batchEnd; batchPosition++)
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Java or Eclipse (or bother) doesn't like this part of the loop:

```
for (batchPostion....
```

It expects the variable being used to count position (*batchPosition*) in the loop to be initialised **in the loop header** (the *for(**f**irst;**o**nly when;**r**epeat)* part.) I would guess this is because wants it to only be local to the loop.

To fix just move you assignment into the header, like so:

```
for (int batchPosition = new Integer (batchBegin);batchPosition<=batchEnd;batchPosition++)
```

Not as pretty, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop contains 4 parts of execution:

initialization, Condition, execution-body, increment or decrement

```
int batchPosition = new Integer(batchBegin);  

for (batchPostion;batchPosition<=batchEnd;batchPosition++)
```

You've missed the initialization part.

Either ignore it at all cause before `for` you've already initialized

```
for (;batchPosition<=batchEnd;batchPosition++)
```

OR

Move the line before `for` to inside `for`

```
for (int batchPosition = new Integer(batchBegin);batchPosition<=batchEnd;batchPosition++)
```

but, in latter case, you won't be able to use `batchPosition` outside `for` scope.